# A drawer contains 10 socks, where 6 of them have holes and 4 of them do not.

Tags: probability

A drawer contains 10 socks, where 6 of them have holes and 4 of them do not. Suppose you pull two random socks out of the drawer, look at them, and then put them back. If you do this 5 times, what is the probability that you pull out a pair with no holes precisely 4 out of 5 times?

Since 6 socks have holes. It means 3 pairs have holes and 2 pairs dont have holes
Is required probability = (3C1.3C1.3C1.3C1.2C1) / 5C2

Comment: Hang on: you're pulling out the _individual_ socks randomly, are you not? Or are they paired up while in the drawer?

Your question suggests the first scenario but your solution suggests the second.

Comment: In this universe earthlings are only quarreling about What is better for to have enough food - a mug or a donut?! - Stomachs are rebelling...

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the socks are to be treated as indistinguishable except for whether they have holes.  In particular, there are no left socks or right socks.

I also assume that you draw two socks out independently of each other.  (For instance, you don't check the first sock to see if it has a hole before drawing the second.)  In that case, the probability that on a given draw, you draw a pair of socks with no holes is

$$
p = \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{6}{45} = \frac{2}{15}
$$

You can then use the binomial theorem to determine the probability of getting a hole-free pair, exactly four times out of five:

\begin{align}
P(\text{exactly $4$ hole-free pairs out of $5$ draws})
  & = \binom{5}{4} p^4 (1-p) \\
  & = 5\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)^4\left(\frac{13}{15}\right) \\
  & = \frac{208}{151875} \doteq 0.0013695
\end{align}